# integrate a jupyter lab editor in React.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jupyter-lab

im trying to create an online editor with react.js that looks like jupyter lab: i want to build the cells, the toolbar etc.
I dont need the functionalities (like running a ipynb file), just the UI

how can i use jupterlab editor as a component / how to integrate it?
are there any extentions that could be used / sample apps already made?

Comment: Yes, there are, e.g. https://github.com/datalayer/jupyter-react, but in general you can just build a small application off JupyterLab components, see https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/tree/master/examples. There were previous discussions about integration with React (not sure whether on gitter/Jupyter discourse or GitHub), have a look. If you have a more specific problem please edit this question as it does not fit the scope of StackOverflow well.